# Is it possible to sign multiple messages using MetaMask all at once?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, web3js, cryptojs, metamask

I have 100 messages that I want to sign using metamask. Is there a way to sign them all at once

I've tried Batchrequest using web3 js but the Metamask ask the user to sign messages one by one

Answer (score 0):

It's not. You cannot sign multiple messages with MetaMask.

Answer (score 0):

you can write an ether.js or a web3.js script to do that work..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).